# User is not logged out when application is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm doing a chat application, however when user terminate the application a good practice for me is loggin out this user and delete it. However when the user is terminating the application if I print something it will be printed, however when i put the code to logout the user the code seems not to be executed I don't know why!

Here it is the code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                
                do{
                    try Auth.auth().signOut()
                    print("user has been logged out without problems!")
                    
                }catch{
                    print("there was an error when trying executing logout function")
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: { (error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                
                do{
                    try Auth.auth().signOut()
                    print("user has been logged out without problems!")
                    
                }catch{
                    print("there was an error when trying executing logout function")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

any solution to execute this code when user terminate the application?

Comment: How does Auth.auth() log the user in and out?

Comment: @GarethPrice when the user enter his email a random password will be generated and he will be logged in, and this function is working with button without problem however it's not working when the application terminate i couldn't figure out why

Comment: You won't have enough execution time to perform a network operation. You can't rely on that method always being called anyway. Why wouldn't you keep the user logged in across executions?  Alternatively just get them to reauthenticate on launch

Comment: @Paulw11 my application is based on speed, so the user doesn't need to do all this steps just username, age and loggin directly you don't need to register or something else, in this case i will be the judge to make sure that the user logout when application terminate and go offline when application is in background

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that that is something you are going to be able to achieve solely on the app side. You may need your app to send "keep alive" messages to the server and for the server to show people as offline after some missed keep alives. The app can be terminated by the user without `willTerminate` being called.

Comment: In the catch block you can get a descriptive text of why exactly your signout function is failing. In the catch block write this code:- "print(error.localizedDescription)" & check what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to stimulate your code, and I noticed the problem.

From what I can tell is (Maybe):

1. The application doesn't provide time to the code to be completed.
2. You are deleting the user, and then sign it out. `Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete`

I tried this code and it seems to be working fine without a problem:

```
    do{
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.delete(completion: nil)
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        print("user has been logged out without problems!")
        
    }catch{
        print("there was an error when trying executing logout function")
    }
```